# discord.py , бот не ловит команды

Tags: python, discord.py

Бот не воспринимает команды

```
import json
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

with open("token.json", 'r') as file:
    passfile = json.load(file)
token = passfile.get('token')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await Bot.process_commands(message)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Вы зачем-то объявили в коде **двух ботов (`bot` и `client`)** и запустили при этом `client — (client.run(token))`. Если вы собираетесь использовать команды, то вам незачем использовать класс `discord.Client`, используйте только `commands.Bot`. Почитать про различия можно здесь: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-discord-py

Comment: И вот эта строчка у вас работать не будет `await Bot.process_commands(message)`, потому что метод `process_commands` нужно вызывать у экземпляра класса, а не у самого класса (`bot` вместо `Bot`). То есть, проверять наличие команды в сообщении должен конкретный (ваш) бот, а не абстрактный `Bot`. Вы же при сложении чисел складываете конкретные числа типа `int` (`1 + 5`), а не `int + int`.